# unable to acquire jdbc connection ejb, jpa, wildfly

Tags: jpa, ejb, wildfly

Wildfly 11 Datasource Config
`

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasource/Ds" pool-name="DS" enabled="true">
                      <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@*.*.*.*:1521:*</connection-url>
                        <driver>oracle</driver>
                        <pool>
                            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                            <initial-pool-size>5</initial-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>500</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>true</prefill>
                            <flush-strategy>EntirePool</flush-strategy>
                        </pool>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>*</user-name>
                            <password*</password>
                        </security>
                        <validation>
                            <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                            <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
                            <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                            <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                            <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
                            <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                            <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                        </validation>
                        <timeout>
                            <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        </timeout>
                    </datasource>
```

`

We will be inserting around 5 lacs of records and we are facing below issue.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4069)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1142)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2762)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2741)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:978)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@3b1bf18c[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@70c4dfaf connection handles=0 lastReturned=1521551768383 lastValidated=1521551264794 lastCheckedOut=1521551468353 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@13dd568e mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@47fbafde[pool=bbpcQA] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@2a6653a9[connectionListener=3b1bf18c connectionManager=1425353e warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options jndiName=java:jboss/datasource/bbpcDS] txSync=null]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
    ... 154 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@3b1bf18c[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@70c4dfaf connection handles=0 lastReturned=1521551768383 lastValidated=1521551264794 lastCheckedOut=1521551468353 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@13dd568e mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@47fbafde[pool=bbpcQA] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@2a6653a9[connectionListener=3b1bf18c connectionManager=1425353e warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options jndiName=java:jboss/datasource/bbpcDS] txSync=null]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:975)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:792)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 158 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:561)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:970)
    ... 160 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple , owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider) is not active STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:296)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:554)
    ... 161 more
```

Comment: How do you use the connection? And which Oracle driver you use? If the transaction is in state ROLLEDBACK is it possible that there is an error before which cause the Tx to rollback?

Comment: Also the exception is about jndiName=java:jboss/datasource/bbpcDS which is not the same name as the configuration you are showing

Comment: @user1454294 were you able to resolve this issue? if so could you please share the solution it will be of great help to the community